# Jquery Looping through a table to find specific TD

Tags: jquery, html

I wish to loop through the table and color the TD of every value  that is negative. Right now it colors the whole row, what can I change to fix it?

http://jsfiddle.net/LEnRj/

### Jquery

```
$('.my-table tr').each(function(index, tr) {
    var lines = $('td', tr).map(function(index, td) {
        return $(td).text();    
    });

    if( lines[1] < 0 ) {
         $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
    }   
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dude, it's jQuery, *write less do more*:

```
$('.my-table td').filter(function() {
    return parseFloat($.trim(this.innerHTML)) < 0;
}).css('background-color', 'red');
```

[**Fixed Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LEnRj/1/)

Comment: That is quite an awesome solution, never heard of filter, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.my-table tr').each(function(index, tr) {
    var lines = $('td', tr).map(function(index, td) {
        if ( $(td).text() < 0 ) $(td).css('background-color', 'red')  #de  Fixed.
        return $(td).text();
    });
})
```

Optimized version:

```
$('.my-table tr td').each(function(index, td) {
    if ( $(td).text() < 0 ) {
        $(td).css('background-color', 'red')
    }
})
```

Comment: **And** if that's all you wanted to do, you don't need the return any more.

Answer (score 0):

You're applying the css to the `<tr>`.  You want to apply it only to the `<td>` that has the negative value.